# Enable data-labels only for specific chart types in a mixed chart

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am trying to show data labels only for the line chart in a mixed/combo chart type (line & bar) but I couldn't find a way to disable it for the bar series.

[it is possible to visualize the code in this link](https://codepen.io/junedchhipa/pen/YJQKOy)
Here is my existing code.

```js
var options = {
      chart: {
        height: 310,
        type: 'line',
        stacked: false,
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Series Column',
        type: 'column',
        data: [23, 11, 22, 27, 13, 22, 37, 21, 44, 22, 30]
      }, {
        name: 'Series Area',
        type: 'area',
        data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43, 21, 41, 56, 27, 43]
      }, {
        name: 'Series Line',
        type: 'line',
        data: [30, 25, 36, 30, 45, 35, 64, 52, 59, 36, 39]
      }],           
      markers: {
        size: 0
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      xaxis: {
        type:'datetime'
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Points',
        },
        min: 0
      },
      

    }

    var chart = new ApexCharts(
      document.querySelector("#chart"),
      options
    );

    chart.render();
```

Is there an option to turn off data-labels for specific series in a mixed chart?

Comment: @markaaronky Sorry; at a glance I couldn't tell the difference; will update my comment.

Comment: I want to leave the data label enabled only in the line chart and not the bar chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: A new option `enabledOnSeries` is shipped in v3.5.0. You can use it like

```
options = {
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    enabledOnSeries: [1, 2]
  }
}
```

The above will show data-labels only for series with index 1,2 and disable data-labels on series with index 0 (in your example - the column series)

Comment: Thank you, I will wait.

Comment: Released a new version 3.5.0 which allows enabling data-labels on specific series - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/#enabledOnSeries

Comment: Is it necessary to download the library again or just add the code to my chart?

Comment: Not necessary to download if you are using the CDN link directly. Please use this - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest

Comment: I made the note for the link that you passed and I added the code to enable the data series, but it is still displaying the labels for all the series. Can you tell me what's wrong in the code below?

Comment: <div id="chart">
  </div> 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@latest"></script>

  <script>   
    var options = {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'line'  
      },
   
   dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
            return val
        },
        textAnchor: 'middle',
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        style: {
            fontSize: '14px'

  </script>

Comment: Edited my answer. Please use the property enabledOnSeries.